# How to do a python regex search from random locations in a large text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a novice at python, but well versed in regex and familiar with programming concepts. I'm trying to find and respond to a set of patterns in a large text file (.rdf) that describe a hierarchy of *collections*. There's a root collection, "collection_2," which may contain one or more *items*, as well as one or more child collections. And so on...

```
parent collection_2
item_17
child collection_44
item_8
item_251
child collection_10
item_3
item_26
...
parent collection_44
item_19
child collection_5
child collection_21
item_106
item_63
...
```

Notice that collection_44 is a child of collection_2, and it's a parent with its own items and child collections, each of which is also a parent. I'm trying to assemble these collections and items into a true hierarchy in a new file.

My code so far is rudimentary, mostly print statements to test my work:

```
import re

rdf_filename = "MyRDF.rdf"
cur_parent = "collection_2"

with open(rdf_filename, "rt", encoding="utf-8") as rdf:
    print("Searching for \"" + cur_parent + "\" in " + rdf_filename)
    if re.search(cur_parent, rdf.read(), re.S):
        print("Found \"" + cur_parent + "\" at index  +, str(rdf.tell()))
        nextindex = str(rdf.tell() + len(cur_parent))
        print("Next search starts at " + nextindex)
```

After I find collection_2, I need to recursively process collection_44 and its child collections, then recursively process collection_10, etc.

Note that each relevant line also contains other data that I need to use, hence the regex (eventually).

If I could use re.search() starting from a specified stream position/index, I think I could figure out the rest, but I can't figure out how to do a pattern search in the middle of a file. I want to avoid reading and searching each line if possible, because there are far more irrelevant lines (20k) than hits in this file.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I want to avoid reading and searching each line if possible" but think of the possibilities if you do. Read line by line and build up the object tree in memory as you do. That may simplify things considerably.

Comment: RDF is xml - using regexes to search XML is very fragile and generally a bad idea, and given it is so easy to use the ElementTree built in library you should bite the bullet and parse it properly - there are plenty of examples. Searching is much easier as the parsed content knows about the hierarchy, tags and attributes.

Comment: Thank you both for some good advice! I wasn't aware of ElementTree.